# How to get all files of all users using google drive API

Tags: admin, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I am a 'domain admin' for a google account and would like to: 
 **Get all of the users in my domain and "for each" user, give another user read-access everyone's files** . I can get each user, but right now I do not understand how to get each users documents.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
from gdata.apps import client

userNameAtGmailCom = 'domainAdmin@someplace.com'
password           = 'mypassword'
personToShareWith  = "someGuy@gmail.com"
domain             = 'someplace.com'

def login(userNameAtGmailCom, password, personToShareWith, domain):
    client = gdata.apps.client.AppsClient(domain=domain)
    client.ssl = True
    client.ClientLogin(email=userNameAtGmailCom, password=password, source='apps')
    all_users = client.RetrieveAllUsers()
    for user in all_users.entry:
                user_name = user.login.user_name
                print user_name
                password = user.login.password
                print password
                clientDocs = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
#password always returns 'none' 
#therefore I've commented out the 'bad authentication'
#that would happen if the lines below ran
                #clientDocs.ClientLogin(user_name, password)
                #documents_feed = clientDocs.GetDocumentListFeed()
                #for document_entry in documents_feed.entry:
                #print document_entry.title.text
                #scope = gdata.docs.Scope(value=personToShareWith, type='user')
                #role = gdata.docs.Role(value='reader')
                #acl_entry = gdata.docs.DocumentListAclEntry(scope=scope, role=role)
                #created_acl_entry = client.Post(acl_entry, document_entry.GetAclLink().href, converter=gdata.docs.DocumentListAclEntryFromString)

login(userNameAtGmailCom, password, personToShareWith, domain)
```

Comment: It seems you need to have already established an auth_token & have it stored within your application: https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/auth/clientlogin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Google Drive API and use service accounts to perform Google Apps domain-wide delegation of authority:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: Thanks Claudio, I've also tried clientDocs 
    clientDocs = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
(and editted my script above to show this) the however, the 'password' returned from each user is always 'none', therefore clientLogin returns bad authentication. ideas?

Comment: For security reasons, you can't retrieve users' passwords using the API. In general, you should never ask other users for their credentials, what you should do is documented at the link in my response.

Comment: Hi Claudio, thanks for your response. I gave up on the drive delegation way because Python can't import "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials". I will try to port to Java instead and see how that goes.