# Admin access to user Google Drive files from installed application with Oauth2

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, gdata, gdata-api

I'm writing a set of Powershell Cmdlets that allow a user to run admin functions on their domain. Using gData I have been able to do provisioning calls to create new users, list groups and other things of that nature. When trying to list another user's documents (as admin) I hit a roadblock with the DocsList api, so I turned to the Google Drive api instead.

I've since been able to get the Drive API working and have a Cmdlet running based on their [QuickStart for DotNet](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) and [File List Example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list). However, I can't seem to figure out how to make it list docs for another user. Everything I've found so far seems to [point to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727206/how-to-get-all-files-of-all-users-using-google-drive-api) the [use of Service Accounts for delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) or [using the old DocList api instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331342/access-to-all-files-on-a-users-google-drive) which is [depreciated](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/retiring-google-documents-list-api-v3.html) in favor of the Drive API anyways.

My problem is the Service Accounts seem to be an alternative to the Installed Application, not something I can use at the same time. Or, if I were able to get it working I would have to have each user [create their own project and service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#create_the_service_account_and_its_credentials), if I'm understanding things.

How can I do this without inconveniencing the users? They've already authenticated themselves as admins, I don't understand why they have to create an API project and service account to achieve the same thing. Would I create a single service account for my API Project? If so, how do I handle the public key it generates and [needs access to?](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object) That doesn't seem very safe if I'm throwing around the key file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can impersonate a user only with service accounts. Once you configure your service account for domain-wide authority, you can make requests with your administrator account as you mention. But, I'm not sure Google Apps allow multiple administrator accounts or not. If they do, all you need is setup a single project and a single service account.

Comment: Just to clarify, that is one service account per domain, right? Keeping in mind that I'm writing a set of tools that other admins would use, those admins would have to go and make their own service accounts to supply the my tools with in order to impersonate other users, yes? If I were to make a service account, I wouldn't hard code it in to the tools, since it would end up having access to all the domains using the tools?