# Google Drive API / Admin: List all files for all users

Tags: google-drive-api

In Google Drive Business, is there a way for an admin to list all files for all users (without transfering ownership)? I am using Dropbox Business and have full control of all files / users, and I am wondering if this is possible in Google Drive for an admin as well.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, this code will list all files shared with the logged user

```
function listFiles() {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'pageSize': 10,
        'fields': "items(id, title, mimeType)"
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log('Files:');
      var items = resp.items;
      if (items && items.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          var file = items[i];
          console.log(file.id + ' (' + file.mimeType + ') ' + file.title);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('No files found.');
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But as an admin I need this for all users. Not only myself.

Comment: don't know if I'm understanding what you need, but I'm just tried this JS code in my account, where I have files shared with me from other users/owner, and I can see that files with this code.

Comment: I have a dropbox business account with several users. And as an admin I am able to see each and every file in there, delete them, etc. With Google Drive for Business this seems not possible. I see only the files that are shared with me.

Comment: Kindly check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727206/how-to-get-all-files-of-all-users-using-google-drive-api). It might help.