# Get all Drive files across all users

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Service Account setup with Domain Wide Delegation. I'd like to search files across all users with a single call.

I'm using the Drive API and the [OAuth2](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) project in Google Apps Script to handle the authentication. It seems like you always have to specify a user to impersonate (code below) when making calls. When I remove the setSubject method I get no results.

Is there a way to do this?

```
  OAuth2.createService('GoogleDrive:' + userEmail)
  // Set the endpoint URL.
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

  // Set the private key and issuer.
  .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
  .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

  // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
  // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
  // delegation:
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
  .setSubject(userEmail)

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

  // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
  // setup of domain-wide delegation.
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
```

Thanks

Comment: You're right to use Service Account setup with Domain Wide Delegation. As stated in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13732646/5832311), You should use the Google Drive API and use service accounts to perform [Google Apps domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation).

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/), you need to return a [`FileIterator`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) which allows scripts to iterate over a potentially large collection of files. Here's a sample [code](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/7ZQgzbcSX68).

Comment: @abielita sorry i wasn't specific enough. I'm already using the Drive API with a Service Account. I've left more detail in the post above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) which can be accessed from apps script through the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). It has additional features compared to DriveApp and allows you to use search queries. You can also use the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list) to test your requests. For example copy the query string from the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) page into the `q` field of the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list). That query string is `"root" in parents and trashed = false and mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"`. If you then click on execute you will see the result. The syntax for the query string is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters).

Comment: Thanks @SpiderPig. Sorry I wasn't specific enough. I've updated the post with more info as I'm using the Drive API but if I don't impersonate a user I get no results back. So was wondering how to make the call without impersonating a user so I can search across all files in 1 call. Thanks