# Google Drive API - List all files for all users for admin of domain

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-drive-api

What I want from google drive api is to have all files list for all user as an admin of domain. but google drive api return only those file which are owned by me. I tried different approaches like I used google service account for domain wide delegations. initially it doesn't work apparently but later I found 
[Google Drive access for Service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382342/google-drive-access-for-service-account)
which give me another direction to share files with service account and it does work. like i was able to list files shared with this account from different users.[image]
But there is problem with this approach. which is all users from domain have to share files with service account and we can't ask users from other domains to do the same for their files to be accessible on our site.

I am looking for a solution where I can see all files from all users associated to logged in person's domain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In G Suite domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as [domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority).

For additional insights, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727206/how-to-get-all-files-of-all-users-using-google-drive-api).

Comment: domain wide delegation doesn't work. I needed to share files with service account then i saw all shared files from other users. What I want to have it is as "if i am an admin i can see drive files from all users"

Comment: @BasitMunir Did you get an answer for your query "What I want to have it is as "if i am an admin i can see drive files from all users" ?